# Typing the Store when imported to typescript pinia vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, import, pinia

**How can I type the Store when imported to typescript pinia vue. Do I need to type it at all?**

```js
    // Component

    <p>{{ storeForm.firstName }}</p>  // getting an error "Property 'storeForm' does not exist on type"


    // Store

    import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useForm = defineStore('login',{
  state: () => ({
    firstName: <string>'',
    lastName: <string>''
  }),
  getters: {
  },
  actions: {
    login(data: any) {
      this.firstName = data.firstName
      this.lastName = data.lastName
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: "does not exist on type" - on which type? How is the error observed, does it occur in IDE or at build too? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's unclear how the component is defined and whether you use TS correctly in Vue. Generally you don't need to type a store, the type is inferred.

Comment: Here is the complete error - Property 'storeForm' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>; ... 10 more ...; $watch<T extends string | ((...args: any) => any)>(source: T, cb: T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? (args_0: R, args_1: R) => ...'.ts(2339)    So, I've added the code of the store file...

Comment: Again, it's unknown how you defined the component and storeForm, there's no `<script>`. The mistake is supposedly there. Please, check what MCVE is it in the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the [`defineComponent()`](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent) wrapper around your component object to have Typescript types:

```js
// Will correctly type your component data, methods etc.
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {}
})
```

Comment: Ok, I wrapped it with a defineComponent but the error is still there. So do I need to type the state I'm importing into the component ?

Comment: I can't help more without additional information. How do you declare `storeForm` in your component?